# How can I troubleshoot this contract deployment script?

Tags: web3js

I have a contract which deploys fine to Goerli and Sepolia via Remix (0xC4c414142B66FB04e2A7c50c7592F5D7696a6a2F and 0x559527Dfe454B717Ee417887127D606E6A7C8e37).

I'm trying to deploy them through a web3.js 4.0.3 script:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3").Web3;
const config = require("../config/web3.json");
const mnemonicPhrase = config.mnemonic;
const compiledFactory = require('./build/MediaContractFactory.json');
let provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {
    phrase: mnemonicPhrase
  },
  providerOrUrl: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/[REDACTED]"
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const account = '[REDACTED]';


const deploy = async () => {
  //const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account ', account);
  try {
    const factory = new web3.eth.Contract(compiledFactory.abi);
    const bytecode = compiledFactory.evm.bytecode.object;
    const gasEstimate = await factory.deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode}).estimateGas();
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    const deployedFactory = await factory.deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode})
    const result = await deployedFactory
      .send({
      gas: gasEstimate,
      from: account,
      gasPrice: gasPrice
    });
    console.log(result);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

};

deploy();
```

This is throwing me the following errors:

Sepolia:

> TransactionBlockTimeoutError: Transaction started at 4057401 but was
> not mined within 50 blocks. Please make sure your transaction was
> properly sent and there no pervious pending transaction for the same
> account. However, be awar e that it might still be mined!
> Transaction Hash: 0xc2402f62a5a3723f707e76571aa713a0f23d1fe8de71985cfb6543e3145e7e5e
> at C:\Users\b_kog\Projects\Ofanym\OfanymFrontend\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\reject_if_block_timeout.js:31:20
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (C:\Users\b_kog\Projects\Ofanym\OfanymFrontend\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\reject_if_block_timeout.js:5:58)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   innerError: undefined,
> code: 432

Goerli:

> Web3ContractError: code couldn't be stored
> at Object.transactionResolver (C:\Users\b_kog\Projects\Ofanym\OfanymFrontend\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\commonjs\contract.js:583:27)
> at C:\Users\b_kog\Projects\Ofanym\OfanymFrontend\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\rpc_method_wrappers.js:378:91
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (C:\Users\b_kog\Projects\Ofanym\OfanymFrontend\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\rpc_method_wrappers.js:21:58)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   innerError: undefined,
> code: 300,   receipt: {
> blockHash: '0xf56ec7c3d036da1cee2f2d6b5310b0de09ccf5c2ab297380533815837cb47695',
> blockNumber: 9490548n,
> contractAddress: '0x6cde0be99910afcf696ed1bd1d58a131a5b32438',
> cumulativeGasUsed: 18326487n,
> effectiveGasPrice: 83722n,
> from: '0xc290af972b2b4af51ce82d9fd72280f1324431d0',
> gasUsed: 1808864n,
> logs: [],
> logsBloom: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
> status: 0n,
> transactionHash: '0x18ae2b3b2738d48ac9a4d5e052e858a2e454bc86e54141efa58f4f9b35a12ace',
> transactionIndex: 70n,
> type: 0n   } }

What might be going on here?